# Making data fit a certain equation form?

Tags: statistics, logarithms

I have a set of data that follows a polynomial (parabola) equation almost perfectly, but I need it to be of the form $T(n) = a\cdot n + b\log(n)$

I approximated it to the polynomial equation using Excel: $y = 6\times10^{-7}x^2 - 0.0637x + 797.18$

I have no idea how I'd go about this, but apparently polynomials can look similar to an equation of that form in some range (but I can't seem to find anything that looks remotely similar when graphing the log function with misc. values for $a$ and $b$ on WolframAlpha).

It doesn't have to be exact at all (as in, you shouldn't have to use a program like Excel).  I basically just need to find an $a$ and $b$ that fit it pretty well.  Am I just supposed to guess until it looks okay?  Or is there some simple way to get somewhat close?

Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: What range of values of $x$ (or $n$) are you interested in ?

Comment: 2^2 to and including 2^9, then 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 32000, 64000, 128000, 256000, 512000, 1024000

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is the range of $x$ (or $n$) values?
Your coefficient of $x^2$ looks suspiciously small.

Your model function is nonlinear, so you would have to use a nonlinear fitting routine.
If Excel can't do it, maybe Wolfram Alpha can.

Also$^2$, you probably need a constant term in your function.
If your $T(n)$ is the time needed to compute some function,
in my experience, there is usually some constant overhead,
and a constant term is needed for that.

You could also set up a simple routine (in Excel or almost anything else)
to to 2-d (or 3-d if you include a constant) bisection:
Divide $a$ and $b$ regions each into a number of points,
try the fit for each of the points,
choose a small sub-region where the fit
seems to be best, and iterate until tired.